# Need help to create a PHP echo script from a range of numbers

Tags: php, list, range

I need a simple script that reads a number from POST (we'll call the value 'number'). It will be a three digit number that must range from the following:

301-340

401-440

501-540

601-640

701-740

801-840

If it doesn't fall in these ranges, I need to echo a message. How would one do this?

Answer (score 1):

```
if($number <= 300 || $number > 840 || (($number-1) % 100) >= 40) {
    echo "Number was not in ranges!";
}
```

This takes advantage of the `%` (modulo) operator which returns the remainder when dividing by a number - so since you're wanting numbers where the remainder modulo 100 is 1-40, it can just subtract one, take it modulo 100, and then see if that is 40+ (since 1-40 is now 0-39).

This approach is nice and concise, as long as your ranges follow that set pattern. If you need more customization of the individual ranges, use a `switch` statement (see the [answer from "too much php"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2799859/need-help-to-create-a-php-echo-script-from-a-range-of-numbers/2799866#2799866) for an example of this).

Answer (score 0):

```
$n = (int)$_POST['number'];
switch(true) {
case $n >= 301 && $n <= 340:
case $n >= 401 && $n <= 440:
case $n >= 501 && $n <= 540:
// ETC
    // number is OK, break out of switch
    break;
default:
    echo "Number '$n' is invalid!<br />";
    exit;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This one is a bit different. Hopefully the array building doesn't add *too* much overhead.

```
// Possible answers
$validInputs = array_merge(range(301, 340), range(401, 440), range(501, 540)); // and so forth...

$input = (int) $_POST['input'];

if ( ! in_array($input, $validInputs)) {
    echo 'Got an error!';
}
```

Relevant docs: [range()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.range.php), [array_merge()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php) and [in_array()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php).